# Random number generator for Ada on BBC MicroBit

Tags: random, ada, bbc-microbit

Working on a little game for the BBC Microbit.

`with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random` reports `"Ada.Numerics" is not a predefined library unit.`

Does Ada provide another way to generate random numbers on the BBC MicroBit?  arch/ARM/Nordic/svd/nrf51/nrf51_svd-rng defines a random number generator record RNG_Peripheral.  Is this what I'm searching for or only used with Bluetooth?

```
GPS 2018 (20180528) hosted on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
GNAT Community 2018 (20180524-73)

Active toolchain: arm-eabi

the GNAT Programming Studio

(c) 2001-2018 AdaCore
```

My code:

```
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;

package body Flip_A_Coin is

   package Random_Coin is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Coin);

   G: Random_Coin.Generator;

   ------------------
   --  Reset       --
   ------------------

   procedure Reset is

   begin

      Random_Coin.Reset(G);

   end Reset;

   ------------------
   --  Flip        --
   ------------------

   function Flip
     return Coin is

   begin

      return Random_Coin.Random(G);

   end Flip;

begin

   Reset;

end Flip_A_Coin;
```

Comment: You named a variable `G` ??!!

Answer (score 4):

If you build using

```
for Runtime ("ada") use "ravenscar-full-microbit";
```

in your project or

```
--RTS=ravenscar-full-microbit
```

on the command line you will find the standard Ada RNGs.

You could also try, as you suggest, using the `NRF51_SVD.RNG` from the [Ada Drivers Library](https://github.com/AdaCore/Ada_Drivers_Library), which should do the trick.

Comment: Are you saying that Ada.Numerics is not available on the Microbit? Could you explain why? I am running into the same problem but concerning Sqrt and Arctan.

Comment: Using the ravenscar-full-microbit runtime as you suggest gives me a host of errors, starting with 'error: "s-stalib.adb" must be compiled' and including a lot of messages about obsolete and read-only files.

Comment: The discussion in (this issue)[https://github.com/AdaCore/Ada_Drivers_Library/issues/91] seems to be about the same underlying problem - the Microbit_ZFP runtime does not give access to the regular Ada libraries.

Comment: `Ada.Numerics.*` is a set of files (`a-numeri.ads` etc, don’t worry) which are included in the ravenscar-full runtime but not in the zfp runtime (zfp => _zero_ footprint). It would be possible to copy them into the zfp runtime and rebuild it ... not for the fainthearted. With regard to your compile errors, first thing to do is to clean out all the `.o`, `.ali` files from your build and try again.

Comment: Thank you Simon. I found [this adacore guide](https://docs.adacore.com/gnathie_ug-docs/html/gnathie_ug/gnathie_ug/the_gnat_configurable_run_time_facility.html#configuring-a-special-purpose-library) specifically showing how to add Ada.Numerics.* to the ZFP library.

Comment: Good! (a) there’s no `math` directory for the CE versions, look in `gnat`, (b) you may need to adjust the `runtime.xml` to include `-lm`, `-lc`, `-lgcc` etc in `package Linker` -- compare to the `ravenscar-full-` version

Comment: The Ada.Numerics RNGs are quite stack-heavy (a simple task using the Discrete RNG needed 4k of stack), which might be a disadvantage, especially on a microbit with 16k SRAM.

Answer (score 1):

If you have floating-point numbers available, you can use U_Rand available @ [Mathpaqs](http://mathpaqs.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of RNGs available in the PragmAda Reusable Components. Maybe one of them will suit you.

[PragmARCs](https://github.com/jrcarter/PragmARC)